# yum update dependency error

Tags: php, linux, centos, updates, yum

Im doing a `yum update`
but I had this error:

```
Error: Package: php56w-opcache-5.6.18-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
       Requires: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.18-1.w6
       Removing: php56w-common-5.6.17-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
           php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.17-1.w6
       Obsoleted By: php-common-5.6.18-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
           Not found
       Updated By: php56w-common-5.6.18-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.18-1.w6
Error: Package: php56w-mysql-5.6.18-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
       Requires: php56w-pdo(x86-64)
       Removing: php56w-pdo-5.6.17-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
           php56w-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.17-1.w6
       Obsoleted By: php-pdo-5.6.18-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
           Not found
       Updated By: php56w-pdo-5.6.18-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php56w-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.18-1.w6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What should I do to fix this?
I tried to use --skip-broken, but it won't update.
Thank you.

Comment: try using different repo.

Comment: Use command `yum repolist` to list all the repo available. I suggest you to use `epel repo` with command `yum --enablerepo=epel install <package>`. If epel is not available than configure it.

Comment: Google how to configure EPEL in RHEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both Webtatic and Remi repositories configured, both provides the PHP stack. This can only raise various conflict issues.

As "remi-php56" is enabled try to install php-opcache and php-mysqlnd (instead of php56w-opcache and php56w-mysql).

P.S. packages in Remi's RPM repository try to facilitate upgrade from other 3rd party repostiory, but some helpers are missing, will be in next version (5.6.19, 7.0.4...)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't run similar repos, it will only give you pain.

You can use the disablerepo command mentioned in the answer above, or manually edit the repos lists in /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo set enabled=0 to disable a repo.

EPEL repos are your best bet for mainstream supported builds